# Underscores _.throttle ignoring input if blur occurs within the timeout

Tags: javascript, meteor, underscore.js

I have a meteor event that watches a set of fields for changes, and updates the database accordingly. For the sake of efficiency (correct me if misguided) I've added a throttle to the event so that it will only fire, at most, once every second.

**Event:**

```
Template.TheForm.events({
  "input #TheForm .field": _.throttle(function (event) {
    // Update field
    Meteor.call("updateForm", this._id, event.target.name, event.target.value, function(error, result){
      // Do someting here
    });
  }, 1000) // Throttle to fire at most once every second
});
```

**Form:**

```
<form id="TheForm">
  <fieldset id="person">
    <legend>The person</legend>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="field" value="{{ name }}" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="field" value="{{ email }}" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The problem is that if I populate a field and blur out of it within the 1000 millisecond timeout only the first character seems to get picked up, i.e.

'Nathan' typed into the `name` field quickly and blurred into the `email` field see's the value in the database return as 'N'.

My understanding was that the `._throttle` function would take the end-result of the field value - even if it means collecting it 1 second later.

From the [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle):

> By default, throttle will execute the function as soon as you call it
>   for the first time, and, if you call it again any number of times
>   during the wait period, as soon as that period is over. If you'd like
>   to disable the leading-edge call, pass {leading: false}, and if you'd
>   like to disable the execution on the trailing-edge, pass  {trailing:
>   false}.

The leading logic seems to work correctly, hence the initial 'N', however I'm not calling `trailing: false` so unless I'm misunderstanding the final value should always be collected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your fields are using the same event handler, so if the second field fires an event within 1 second, some events from the first field will be suppressed. If you type "Nathan" in the `name` field within 1 second, your handler will be called for `name=N` and then 1 second later with `name=Nathan`. But if you switch over to the `email` field and type some characters (say "nathan@e") in there quickly enough then those events will cause the `name=Nathan` event to be suppressed. In this case you'll get `name=N` immediately and `email=nathan@e` 1 second later.

The solution is therefore to have a separate throttled event handler for each input field. You don't necessarily have to copy-paste the event handler multiple times - you can use an approach like this:

```
var throttledFunctions = {};
["name", "email"].forEach(function (fieldName) {
    throttledFunctions[fieldName] = _.throttle(function (context, event) {
        Meteor.call("updateForm", context._id, event.target.name, event.target.value, ...)
    }, 1000);
});

Template.TheForm.events({
    "input #TheForm .field": function (event) {
        throttledFunctions[event.target.name](this, event);
    } 
});
```

Comment: I had feared that was the case - as I'm sure you can imagine it will add rather a lot of redundancy to the code (as I'd have a dozen near-identical events). I had looked into debounce initially but had decided throttle made more sense for my use-case - I'll have another look as I may have simply misunderstood. My worry was more that if the user was completing a large textarea with no pause in input and for whatever reason the session died then all of that input would be lost - with throttle you'd only lose the last X seconds of input. It is an edge case though.

Comment: In the case of a textarea then I guess it makes sense to use throttle over debounce. You don't have to copy-paste the event handler for each field though.

Comment: But you stated that "The solution is therefore to have a separate throttled event handler for each input field." - getting mixed messages here :)

Comment: Using debounce does fix the issue I reported though. It makes for less smooth two-way data display (as the updates are less frequent) but in turn that renders it more efficient, I guess. (Cancel that, doesn't fix it, just changes it slightly, there's no shortcut here :) Your solution seems nice and tidy though)

Comment: I may be being dumb here but I'm getting 'throttledFunctions[event.target.name] is not a function' in the console when attempting to use this solution.

Comment: Ok it was me being dumb, I'd used slightly different input `name`s than I used in my question so I needed to update them, no more console errors… however nothing is updating :/ No errors at all though so I'll go on a hunt. (I'd caught the lack of a `wait` on the throttle already, but thanks for editing that in)

Comment: More dumbness - I hadn't replaced the `this._id` with `context._id` in the new function. Works a treat, thanks for your help!